# Wikipedia API: how to search for a term in a specific category

Tags: api, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I'm having hard time to figure out a basic task: how to find a term
restricted in a specific category..

i feel Wiki API documentation is kinda confusing...

I'd just like to receive as output a JSON file with all the suggestions related to that term

> ex. i search for Matrix, category
>   movies, so i can have  The Matrix 1
>   The Matrix 2 etc excluding math
>   results etc...

thanks

Answer (score 17):

I feel your pain bro, try something like:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&format=jsonfm&srsearch=matrix+incategory:English-language_films

Change the above format from jsonfm to json for real json output.

Answer (score 3):

You can't tell the API to only return articles from a category that match a certain criteria, unfortunately. You can, however, tell the API to return articles in a specific category, such as ["1990s science fiction films"](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmlimit=500&cmtitle=Category:1990s%20science%20fiction%20films), and then use another programming language such as PHP or JavaScript to then return the articles that match your specified criteria.