# mediawiki api. how to chose page from response

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

When I make api query sometimes I have list with few pages. For example
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ask gives a lot of pages,  I need  website "Ask.com, a web search engine, formerly Ask Jeeves"
can I make query only for some category ("websites")?
How I can check category for each page in response?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no trivial way to do what you're asking. You could do something like this:

1. Get the list of pages the disambiguation page list. You could do this by listing the links on that page (`action=query&prop=links`).
2. Get the categories of all the pages from the previous step and use that to decide which one is the one you're looking for. This is not that simple, because `Ask.com` is not directly in `Category:Websites`, it's in one of its subcategories.

Answer (score 1):

> I have list with few pages, for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ask

The problem is that you're not getting a list of pages, you just are getting an ordinary page which is in the [*disambiguation pages* category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aDisambiguation_pages). To get the list, you need to get the [links in that page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aProperties#links_.2F_pl).

> can I make query only for some category ("websites")?

No, mediawiki does not support that.

> How I can check category for each page in response?

Use the `links` property as a [title list generator](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aQuery#Generators) and get the [categories of each page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aProperties#categories_.2F_cl) in the response. In your case, that would be [`http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Ask&generator=links&prop=categories`](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Ask&generator=links&prop=categories&gpllimit=max&cllimit=max) (don't forget to `continue` the query).

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK with "full-text search" for "ask",
you can do that like this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&gsrsearch=ask%20incategory:%22Online%20companies%22&prop=info

As you can see, "search" text is [ask incategory:"Online companies"]

The same solution also can be seen at:
[Wikipedia API: how to search for a term in a specific category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240517/wikipedia-api-how-to-search-for-a-term-in-a-specific-category)